# How to determine if user is on same road as GPS coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, gps

I have an GPS based iPhone application that uses Google Maps. The app simply displayes the users current location on the map and will alert users when they come to within a certain radius of a marked Point on their journey.

For legal reasons I am unable to use turn-by-turn navigation in the app so the app will never know the route the user is taking to get from A to B. All the app does is constantly check current location agains a database of GPS Point coordinates. If the users current location is within e.g. 50 meters of a Point, the user will get a message regarding that Point.

My issue is this:
Each Point has a radius of say 50 meters around it as marked by the large blue circle on the image below.

The user is indicated by small blue dot and the direction of travel is marked by the red arrow. In the image the user has entered the radius of the Point but is not actually on the same road as the Point. The user should only get messages should they be on the same road as the Point and within the radius of the Point.

Is there a way I can determine if the user is on the same road as thePoint when entering that Points radius?

Side Note: The app is working in its current state and I can get messages when entering the radius of a Point.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been implementing gps based track and trace apps for a while. The easiest way I see is when you get the event that the point is entering the 50 m radius you do a geolookup meaning you ask the system the address of the long/lat. You compare this (street) with the geolookup of your ref point.

This requires a geolookup service and the user being online.

Comment: How does this fare with performance? I will have to check the current street address each loop of the thread to always have the current street name I am on. And when I hit a Points radius I will have to do a reverse geo-lookup of the points address in a block ^ to get the Points address and then check against my current street address? Or is there a better way to do it than what I have described? Will the way I describe be too time consuming or drain the battery of the phone in no time at all?

Comment: Typically you use the `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` of the `CLLocationManager` to +- configure the number of postion updates per minute. I usually don’t use blocks but use the function  ` (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation function to get notification of the position update` from the `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: Power consumption is indeed an issue, certainly if you are requesting the highest resolution from the GPS (which in your case, since you are talking about a 50m radius, is probably needed). Also using the datanetwork will use power. I would advise, to use the `distanceFilter` sensibly, it's no use in trying to launch a geolookup call each 25 meter (but this actually depends on the speed you are moving), as the datanetwork (if its on mobile) will not be fast enough anyway.

Comment: Regarding performance, make sure that you wait for initiating another geolookup, until the previous is finished. You do not want to endup in a scenario where you are initiating to many geolookup calls and the system cannot follow...

Comment: Thanks HixField. A lot of really handy tips in there. I will have a go at this ASAP and mark this question as correct as soon as I get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a circle, you should use a rectangle defined when creating each point. Or use both: test rectangle of the street once inside the circle if your rectangle is too approximate. You can find out approximate edges of the rectangle by testing geolookup different point of the circles at the beginning.